# Should we denormalize our data after normalization?

Tags: neural-network, lstm, normalization, feature-scaling

If we use `sklearn` library's `preprocessing.normalize()` function to normalize our data before learning, like this:

```
preprocessing.normalize(training_set)
model.add(LSTM())
```

Should we do a `denormalization` to the result of `LSTM` to get predicted result in a true scale? If yes, how to denormalize?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in Python using `scaler.inverse_transform`.

Consider a dataset that has been normalized with **MinMaxScaler** as follows:

```
# normalize dataset with MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

# Training and Test data partition
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.8)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

# reshape into X=t-50 and Y=t
previous = 50
X_train, Y_train = create_dataset(train, previous)
X_test, Y_test = create_dataset(test, previous)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))
```

Upon generating the predictions from LSTM, the same can be converted back using `scaler.inverse_transform` as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, previous)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
trainpred = model.predict(X_train)
testpred = model.predict(X_test)
trainpred = scaler.inverse_transform(trainpred)
Y_train = scaler.inverse_transform([Y_train])
testpred = scaler.inverse_transform(testpred)
Y_test = scaler.inverse_transform([Y_test])
predictions = testpred
```

Comment: May I ask, how would we inverse normalise the "out-of-time" forecast? For the completely new time-tick forecast $t+1$ we can't use the min/max, computed up to the $t$ tick - correct?

Answer (score 3):

The implication in your question is that you're normalising the target variable as well as the predictors. In general, I think that's probably not the right thing to be doing, and that you should be excluding the target from normalisation. That being the case, no inverse transformation after training should be necessary.